# How to reuse a component code (Angular2 + TS)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, reusability

Creating a small Angular 2 app (A calculator for a nice game called AbyssRium), I'm trying to reuse the code of a simple component that shows a list of elements. I want those components to show only a subset of elements (filtered by group).

I'm not sure if it's possible to do it using the RouteConfig (passing a parameter), but it would be a good option. I tried to understand 'Routes' the documentation ([here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#!?query=route) and [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) ) but I couldn't see any clear reference (now playing with [Resolve](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard), but no results yet). I'm looking for something like this:

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/corals', name: 'Corals', component: ItemsList, data:{group:'coral'}, useAsDefault: true},
  {path: '/fishes', name: 'Fishes', component: ItemsList, data:{group:'fish'}},
])
```

I also tried to inherit the module (ItemsList -> ItemsCoralList & ItemsFishList), and initialize the class (this.group = "coral") in the constructor, but tons of compilation errors appear:

> Cannot resolve 'xxx'. Make sure they all have valid type or annotations.

Any idea how to do it without copying all the code twice?

Here the code at [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DRx1oH0Y3iLgOJy0YyrJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
{path: '/:group', component: ItemsList}
```

And access it via router

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => params.group)
}
```

Note: this is Router 3.x syntax, it's probably not gonna work out of the box - you should upgrade to final...

Comment: How can I use this routes in the template? It has no name, so I don't know how to call it.  <a [routerLink]="coral">Corals</a>  raises an error.